# conditions within brace blocks

Tags: awk

To make multiple passes on the same input file, this simple case works fine:

```
$ awk 'p==1{print $1}; p==2{print $2}; p==3{print $3}' p=1 infile p=2 infile p=3 infile
```

But fail with this change?

```
$ awk 'p==1{/Jan/ {print $1}}; p==2{print $2}; p==3{print $3}' p=1 infile p=2 infile p=3 infile
```

I don't want to use terms like:

```
p==1 && /Jan/ {print $1}
```

as I want to maintain the readable structure of the (original) code.

How can I use a conditional terms inside each bracket?

Example:

```
$ cat infile
James   Exeter 48
Alex    Leeds  22
Jan     London 35
```

desired result:

```
Jan
Exeter
Leeds
London
48
22
35
```

Comment: It's extremely unusual to need to do multiple passes of the same input file so there's probably a better approach for you. Ask a new question if you'd like more help with whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/regexp/` operator is an operator that returns 1 if `$0` matches the regexp and 0 otherwise.

You can use it as `print /foo/ + /bar/` for instance, or `if (/foo/) print "match"` or in the `CONDITION` part of a `CONDITION { ACTION }` statement, but using it as part of the `ACTION` in `/foo/ {something}` is invalid syntax, the same way `a == b {something}` or `"whatever" {something}` is invalid there.

You'd want:

```
awk '
  p==1 {
    if (/Jan/) print $1
    next
  }
  p==2 {print $2; next}
  p==3 {print $3; next}
  ' p=1 infile p=2 infile p=3 infile
```

Also note the calls to `next` to avoid testing for `p==2` and `p==3` if `p==1` matched for instance.

Here, you could also just do:

```
awk '{print $p}' p=1 infile p=2 infile p=3 infile
```

Or to only print records matching `/Jan/` when `p==1`:

```
awk 'p != 1 || /Jan/ {print $p}' p=1 infile p=2 infile p=3 infile
```

`$` is also an operator, you can use `$p` or `$ p` or `$ (p * 2 - p)` or `$ (field_to_print = p)` which all invoke the `$` operator to expand to the p<sup>th</sup> field¹.

With the GNU implementation of `awk` (also called `gawk`), you can use `ARGIND` which is incremented for each argument instead of having to set `p` yourself:

```
gawk 'ARGIND != 1 || /Jan/ {print $ARGIND}' infile infile infile
```

---

<sup>¹ Or the whole record if p == 0</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Stephane. I can see that **if(/Jan/) print** works as part of the ACTION. So why not **/Jan/ {print}** or **/Jan/ print** ? What is the general rule?

Comment: @elmo, see the [grammar for standard awk language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/awk.html#tag_000_000_108_016) for the *general rule*.

Comment: If you don't have GNU awk for ARGIND variable you could use FNR variable : `gawk 'FNR==1 {ifile+=1} ifile == 1 { if (/Jan/) {print $ARGIND} } ifile > 1 {print $ifile}' infile infile infile`

Comment: @ArnaudValmary, beware that in the general case, `FNR == 1` doesn't trigger for empty file, so it doesn't always increment for each file.  `BEGINFILE` doesn't have the problem but is also a gawkism.

Answer (score 0):

[@StéphaneChazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) [answered your specific question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767104/133219) but to be clear - you don't need to do multiple passes of the input file to do what you're trying to do, you could just do it in 1 pass, e.g.:

```
$ awk '/Jan/{print $1} {a=a $2 ORS; b=b $3 ORS} END{printf "%s%s", a, b}' infile
Jan
Exeter
Leeds
London
48
22
35
```

or more generally for any number of fields:

```
$ awk '/Jan/{print $1} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=a[i] $i ORS} END{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s", a[i]}' infile
Jan
Exeter
Leeds
London
48
22
35
```

That would only fail if your input file was absolutely massive, too big to fit in memory.

Comment: Thanks Ed for your comment. My question was simply meant to highlight a puzzling behaviour: awk allows regex outside braces but not inside. Why? It is so illogical. If you can use if() statements inside the braces then why not regex? It is a wrinkle in awk logic that has always bothered me.

Comment: Yeah, I found awk syntax pretty confusing whern I started learning it (but that was also old, broken awk which didn't help). Think of awk as C (or any other Algol-based language of your choice) streamlined JUST for manipulating text. What does EVERY program that manipulate text need? - a) a loop reading lines of input, b) field splitting (code to break each line up into substrings), and c) pattern matching (code to test for the presence of strings in the input and do something when true). So awk has those built-in and everything else is basically a tiny subset of C.

Comment: Awk has `a` built in populating `$0` but you can write `while ( getline line ) {...}` instead if you like. Similarly awk has `b` built in populating `$1`, `$2`, etc. but you can write `{ split($0,a) }`, and awk has `c` built in as `<condition> { <action> }` but you can write `{ if ( <condition> ) { <action> } }`. So awk is simply a tiny subset of C with those 3 additional functionalities added to facilitate text manipulation as robustly, efficiently, and concisely as possible. Not sure if that helps you any but once I understood that awk became perfectly clear and obvious.

Comment: As for why you can't use `<condition>` inside an action `{ <condition> { <action> } }` - awk is a tiny language because the providers only implement functionality that's hard for users to implement using existing constructs. It's trivial to write `{ if (<condition>) { <action> } }` and that's also very clear and familiar to everyone who's ever done any programming in just about any language. Given that, there's simply no reason to support the very slightly briefer but more confusing `{ <condition> { <action> } }`.

Comment: Fair enough ED I accept your reasoning. I think I can live with this. Many thanks for taking the time to explain.